# Manipulating Sentinel-1 SAR Imagery to get Pixel Information

Tags: python, remote-sensing, sar, sentinel

For S1 SAR imagery data, how would I go about accessing the data of individual pixels? I need to analyze pixel intensity based on their lat and lon coordinates. I know this information is viewable in SNAP, but I need to analyze a lot of information, so I need a way to do this in python. I'm looking through the pyroSAR documentation but nothing seems to discuss this issue.

This is the file I'm starting with.
S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20190911T225046_20190911T225111_028980_034973_7D9E.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only concerned with one scene, you can convert the image into geotif using SNAP and then you can use either GDAL or rasterio functionalities. If your concern is on large number of scenes, you can use SNAP graph builder, prepare a work flow, save it as xml file and create loop functoin that can iteratively process each scene on defined procedures on graph xml.

Comment: Thanks! The method I have right now to create a subset in SNAP and export as a netCDF file - this file is 900MB and very slow to work with, so I'll have to read more about GDAL and rasterio

Answer (score 0):

The data can be exported from SNAP in a number of data file formats including HDF5 and NetCDF. These are databases of pixels with intensity data and other properties, and they can be imported into pandas dataframes.